# Bot Framework Dialog Chain Returning Value twice?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to make sense of [Dialog Chaining](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html#Fluent) in the Microsoft Bot Framework for C#.

When I say "1" it returns "said 1" twice, when I say "2" it returns "said 2" twice, etc.  I do not understand why this is returning a value twice. I also noticed that if a breakpoint is set in Test, it will never be hit. What is it I am not understanding about Dialog Chains? I have looked at the [SimpleFacebookAuth example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot/SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.cs#L87) already.

I have a simple class TestDialog.
In MessagesController.cs I instantiate it like:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => TestDialog.dialog);

        }
    }
```

Here is TestDialog.cs

```
public class TestDialog : IDialog<string>
    {

        public static readonly IDialog<string> dialog = Chain
            .PostToChain()
            .Switch(

                new Case<IMessageActivity, IDialog<string>>((msg) =>
                {
                    var regex = new Regex("^1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    return regex.IsMatch(msg.Text);
                }, (ctx, msg) =>
                {
                    return Chain.Return("said 1");
                }),


                 new Case<IMessageActivity, IDialog<string>>((msg) =>
                 {
                     var regex = new Regex("^2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                     return regex.IsMatch(msg.Text);
                 }, (ctx, msg) =>
                 {
                     return Chain.Return("said 2");
                 }),



                new DefaultCase<IMessageActivity, IDialog<string>>((ctx, msg) =>
                {
                        return Chain.Return("default");
                })
            ).Unwrap().PostToUser();


        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await Test(context);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {

                await Test(context);
        }


        private async Task Test(IDialogContext context)
        {

            if (true)
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Done("done");
            }
        }

    }
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I've used chain dialog; however, because of these problems and also not supporting some ideas, I've preferred using context.call and context.forward which are written inside dialog to chain dialog.